Is the test/offering for jealousy done by a Priest in Numbers similar to divination?
Divination is described as: A widespread cultural practice that involves using signs, techniques, and visions to understand the underlying causes of situations and to foretell the future.
In Numbers 5 (NIV) it reads:

15 then he is to take his wife to the priest. He must also take an
offering of a tenth of an ephah of barley flour on her behalf. He
must not pour olive oil on it or put incense on it, because it is a
grain offering for jealousy, a reminder-offering to draw attention to
wrongdoing.
16 “‘The priest shall bring her and have her stand before the Lord.
17 Then he shall take some holy water in a clay jar and put some dust
from the tabernacle floor into the water.
18 After the priest has had the woman stand before the Lord, he shall
loosen her hair and place in her hands the reminder-offering, the
grain offering for jealousy,while he himself holds the bitter water
that brings a curse.
19 Then the priest shall put the woman under oath and say to her, “If
no other man has had sexual relations with you and you have not gone
astray and become impure while married to your husband, may this
bitter water that brings a curse not harm you.
20 But if you have gone astray while married to your husband and you
have made yourself impure by having sexual relations with a man other
than your husband”—
21 here the priest is to put the woman under this curse—“may the Lord
cause you to become a curse[b] among your people when he makes your
womb miscarry and your abdomen swell.
22 May this water that brings a curse enter your body so that your
abdomen swells or your womb miscarries.”
“‘Then the woman is to say, “Amen. So be it.”

Is this test/offering for jealousy more like a psychic or divination kind of thing? In comparison to asking a ouiji board a yes or no question. If she commited adultery the water will curse her. If she didn’t it won’t. I could be wrong. Was it correct for a priest to do this?

Short Answers: Is this test/offering for jealousy more like a psychic or divination kind of thing? No.
Was it correct for a priest to do this? Yes.
While it might seem similar to divination because it seeks to reveal hidden knowledge, there is a very key difference:
Who's authority?
We know this was a ritual performed by a priest to determine the guilt or innocence of a woman accused by her husband of adultery.
Here's the thing, in divination, the knowledge often comes from interpreting signs, omens, or supernatural entities. In the case of the ordeal of the bitter water, the knowledge comes from God. The priest performs the ritual, but it is God who ultimately reveals the truth.
Divination is used for things like, predicting the future or to gain advice for personal decisions. The ordeal of the bitter water is used specifically to bring to light the truth. It's not about predicting something it's about learning the truth.

In the ritual, the answer is believed to come directly from God. Sure, the priest performs the ritual, but it’s God who reveals the truth. In contrast, a Ouija board is often believed to channel spirits or other supernatural entities to reveal answers.
The ritual is specifically designed to determine the guilt or innocence of a woman accused of adultery. A Ouija board is used to answer a very wide range of questions, not just questions of guilt or innocence.

Thanks. A ritual to find out the truth just sounded like Ouija when you ask questions to find out the truth. But, I get it.

The jealousy ritual receives an extensive treatment in the gospel of John, where Jesus sort of performs it, twice: for the Samarian Woman (John 4:13) and the woman caught in adultery (John 8:8)

John 4:13 - - Jesus said to her, “Everyone who drinks of this water will be thirsty again
John 8:7 - - And once more he bent down and wrote on the ground.

Between them, John 4 and John 8 include substantially all the steps of the prescription in Numbers 5. Which is great because it makes Numbers 5 one of the only bits of the Mosaic Law for which we've got any sort of worked example.
And if the OP is anxious about superstition or primitivity or psychic divination, hopefully it will immediately leap out to them that while the scribes and Pharisees want to skip straight to stoning at John 8:5, Jesus recognizes her right to the jealousy ritual.
Which might make this more like a medieval-style trial-by-ordeal. And so in the history-of-ideas the ancient Jews perhaps aren't primitive but centuries ahead of their time.
We can make an educated guess that Jesus' usage of the ritual is going to be somewhat ironic or back-handed, since (by John's time) that's the usual/traditional way he shows up the Pharisees. What's interesting is:-

nobody seems to notice (so perhaps this ritual isn't well-remembered)

Jesus combines the dust and the writing into writing-in-dust

if the first woman had five husbands the ritual probably wasn't oppressing her much in practice

the ritual remains important if the person has been caught in the act (John 8:4), so it's not really for divination at all

the Pharisees though must think it's for divination, and therefore they ignore it having caught the second woman in the act. So it's reasonable to take John 8 as a warning against misinterpreting Numbers 5 as a divination ritual, and reminding it serves some other purpose.



It's now better to return to Numbers 5 itself, having provided a categorical answer to the OP's contention, and armed with some ideas of what issues a later religious group felt they were able to raise with it.
Self-evidently this ritual is going to be a complete waste of time for anyone whose partner's adultery hasn't produced a pregnancy (or miscarriage). And not just time - barley's your livelihood or daily bread (and it's barley not the nice white grain, since adultery is a spiritual concern at every level of income). At verse 22 that's the only outcome - the woman will turn out to be pregnant or not. That's hardly divination! It's the opposite - was the ritual always entirely ironic?
The ritual doesn't reveal or curse adultery short of pregnancy. It might be that without witnesses or a confession or a pregnancy, the adultery has remained a domestic matter capable of human resolution without the religious court. That would mean the original prescription was for people to sort their own stuff out as far as possible, and later the authoritarians conveniently forget about it so they can interfere in people's lives as much as possible. Well, we do see that happen in our time.
And if the adultery leads to a pregnancy, the ritual seems to leave that to God. If the curse is the curse handed down to Adam in the beginning. This ritual might even indirectly obstruct stoning a pregnant woman to death for adultery. Which would be jolly progressive! (afaik) there's no historical or literary records of them actually stoning pregnant women to death, and the Rabbinic jurisprudence that an unborn foetus is water (e.g. Ohalot 7:6) might be ~200 years later.
For the women who could avail themselves of this legal procedure - it potentially gets them out of mob violence situations for long enough for their pregnancy to show. Yes the curse at 5:21 (וְלִשְׁבֻעָ֖ה) is (i) serious e.g. Deuteronomy 29:20 "he Lord will blot out his name from under heaven." and (ii) collective (e.g. at Joshua 7 Israel suffers defeat in battle because of a curse on one person, Achan) so the woman's family are placed at risk by her... but the way Numbers 5:21 makes the woman a curse among her family might protect her from them.
At the very top of this code of laws in Deuteronomy 5:9, God is content for the ones he curses for idolatry against himself to go on to have great-grandchildren - so the punishment can't have been death. And at least some people in the early 1st Century seem to have taken that sort of a view and been able to make a convincing case for it.

Thanks. I learned a lot of new things. It would be nice to know all of this instead of listening to the Word on YouVersion and being left stumped. Good thing I can just ask! :)
